# Is it possible to make a CSS cascading drop-up menu (mirror of drop-down)?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, flyout

I started on doing this, and I thought; oh this will be easy, but I got stuck when the fly-out covers up the other categories.

I don't even know if I can do this! My CSS skills are quite rusty!

Here's what I started, but it's really not even good:
+ http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbYzwr

```
             [===========]
[===========][===========]
[===========][===========]
[===========][===========]
[-----------][===========]
[===========]
[:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::]
```

If this is the menu, then because the lower categories when they are flown-out invisibly cover up the ones above them, you can't hover over them!

It's supposed to be like the LXDE panel menu (lxpanel).

On LXDE, the fly-out items start from the top, unless they would go below the screen, in which they are appropriately offset. I can't think of a way to do that with CSS. Can you? The only way I can think of is to let the fly-out items start from the bottom, but what's the special trick to get that to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `margin-left: 100px;` to `[category] > ul` instead of `button`.

[I've forked your pen here](http://codepen.io/WashingtonGuedes/pen/OyPJyb).

Comment: I should have thought of that. I am so out of it. That was so obvious.